# Actionscript security sandbox violation

Tags: flash, http, actionscript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am writing a Photoshop plugin as an ExtendScript (Javascript) file, that then loads up a Flash window, which I will call plugin.swf - My plugin.swf file uses an  element to POST to a certain URL. 
When I load plugin.swf with Internet Explorer, the HTTP POST is completed successfully. 
When I load plugin.swf via the Javascript (which is called via the File -> Scripts menu of Adobe Photoshop), the HTTP POST returns the following:

---

...
target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
text = "Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file://{location of my .swf} cannot load data from {location where I'm trying to send HTTP POST}."
type = "securityError"
timestamp = 0
timeToLive = 0
...

---

Why will the HTTP POST work when loading the .SWF file through Internet Explorer, but not work when loaded through Adobe Photoshop?

Edit: Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Because a swf loaded from the filesystem has a different security sandbox than one loaded in Flash's internal flash player or one loaded in a browser.  Not sure how you'd get around that issue; I don't think a policy server would help in this case.

What happens if you try to open a new window via Javascript from the script (which would be a page on the web - not your filesystem - that embedded the swf)?  I'm not sure if it would be disregarded altogether or use your default browser.  If that doesn't work, you're most likely out of luck.